# PHP file included but code not working

Tags: php, mysql, include

I am trying to connect mysql from within PHP function. The credentials are stored in a separate PHP file, which I am including it inside the function. But when I run the script, I am getting following error:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in C:\xamp
p\htdocs\abc\test.php on line 12. Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)    


private function insertToMysql()
{
    include_once('connect_db.php');

    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die('Oops connection error -> ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $connection) or die('Database error -> ' . mysql_error());

    //Queries

}
```

I tried echoing the include_once and it returned 1. This means, the connect_db.php is included, but somehow the constants are not loaded. What could be the issue??? The credentials are perfect and I verified them. I am not a newbie to PHP.

Contents of connect_db.php:

```
<?php
  define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', '<MyPassword>');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'testdb');
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of connect_db.php with sensitive info X'ed out of course.

Comment: Have you tried to echo $connection to see if it is ok? Are all your mysql_query() commands in the function after '//Queries'?

Comment: The error occurs in the mysql_query(). You should post the hole code, because the posted lines seem to be perfectly correct. Also, you shouldn't use mysql_, because it's deprecated.

Comment: Both `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` seem to be correct. Otherwise you should see either error 'Oops ...' or error 'Database error ...'.

Comment: Do NOT use the insecure mysql_* API anymore, it is deprecated! Instead use PDO or mysqli with preared statements. Read up on good PHP practice on http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: that was a fake password ...!! Thanks for editing anyways!!

Comment: I'm guessing the database information is in the file, so therefore, the connection code needs to be there as well. Let me try putting connection info into connect_db.php itself...

Comment: yes..it worked...thanks guys for trying to help...also I'll incorporate the PDO or MySQLi as suggested instead of mysql_*. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `$connection` is a local variable, you can fix this by making it global.

Do this like this.

```
include_once('connect_db.php');
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die('Oops connection error -> ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $connection) or die('Database error -> ' . mysql_error());

function insertToMysql()
{
    //Queries
    mysql_query('Some query');
}
```

Comment: Making connection global would be kind of insecure.

Comment: Wouldn't it make it unencapsulated? (Assuming the function is in a class)

Comment: In this case you are right but this is not a good way either, connection should be made one time, not in every function call.

Comment: So your saying connection should be a static variable or in a static method?

Comment: no it just need scope up, you can define it by public or private in class

Comment: i am now using the mysqli extension instead of deprecated mysql extension

Answer (score 0):

remove connection handler

```
private function insertToMysql()
{
    include_once('connect_db.php');

    mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die('Oops connection error -> ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die('Database error -> ' . mysql_error());

    //Queries

}
```